# Android screenrecorder crash when writing to external storage

Tags: android

I'm using this code as base for my app: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MediaProjection/andcorder

Now i changed the path for the output file. I want to save it on the external sd card, but if i start recording, i get this error:

```
09-24 01:37:50.225 4428-4428/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder, PID: 4428
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder.RecorderService@1febce5 with Intent { act=me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder.RECORD flg=0x10000000 cmp=me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder/.RecorderService bnds=[257,1321][832,1513] }: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception preparing recorder
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3045)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:157)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1454)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception preparing recorder
                                                                                 at me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder.RecordingSession.start(RecordingSession.java:98)
                                                                                 at me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder.RecorderService.startRecorder(RecorderService.java:169)
                                                                                 at me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder.RecorderService.onStartCommand(RecorderService.java:76)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3028)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:157) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1454) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
                                                                              Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/3E0D-1BF9/20160924_013750.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
                                                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                                                 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:117)
                                                                                 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:149)
                                                                                 at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:780)
                                                                                 at me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder.RecordingSession.start(RecordingSession.java:89)
                                                                                 at me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder.RecorderService.startRecorder(RecorderService.java:169) 
                                                                                 at me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder.RecorderService.onStartCommand(RecorderService.java:76) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3028) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:157) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1454) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
                                                                              Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
                                                                                 at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                                                 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                                                 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:117) 
                                                                                 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:149) 
                                                                                 at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:780) 
                                                                                 at me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder.RecordingSession.start(RecordingSession.java:89) 
                                                                                 at me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder.RecorderService.startRecorder(RecorderService.java:169) 
                                                                                 at me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder.RecorderService.onStartCommand(RecorderService.java:76) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3028) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:157) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1454) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder">

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_videocam_white_24dp"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name="me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder.RecorderService"
        android:exported="true" />
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

I already put in the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
WRITE_SETTINGS is to set show touches.

The most interesting line should be:
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/3E0D-1BF9/20160924_013750.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
, where /storage/3E0D-1BF9/ is my external sd card. But why "Permission denied"? I added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Any idea?

Edit 1: I added this to onCreate in my Main / Settings and only Activity:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, RecorderService.NOTIFY_ID);
```

where RecorderService.NOTIFY_ID is just an int

and checked it with:

```
showToast(String.valueOf(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) + " " +
                String.valueOf(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) + " " +
                String.valueOf(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED));

static void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(appContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The Output was: "true false true"

WRITE_SETTINGS stays false :(
... but if I can save the video to the external sd card instead, it's ok. Maybe we will find a fix for this too ;)

Now WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is allowed, the problem SHOULD be resolved, but it still doesn't work. If I can guess why:
To request a permission, the method needs an activity. Does this mean, that every activity has to request the permission? The problem with this is: The recorder is a Service. I can't request a permission without an activity.

Edit 2: Example:
In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder.MainActivity"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
package me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        boolean canWrite = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        textView.append("WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: " + canWrite + "\n");

        if(canWrite) {
            textView.append("Befor: " + new File("/storage/emulated/0/z.txt").exists() + " " + new File("/storage/6301-17FC/z.txt").exists() + "\n");

            writeToFile("Unglaublich wichtig", "/storage/emulated/0/z.txt");
            writeToFile("Unglaublich wichtig", "/storage/6301-17FC/z.txt");

            textView.append("After: " + new File("/storage/emulated/0/z.txt").exists() + " " + new File("/storage/6301-17FC/z.txt").exists() + "\n");
        } else {
            textView.append("Please restart this app after granting permission.");
        }
    }

    private static void writeToFile(String s, String f) {
        File file = new File(f);
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
            writer.append(s);
            writer.close();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Result of this example code:
On /storage/emulated/0 (internal) the file gets created, on /storage/6301-17FC (my external sd card) not.

Edit 3: I tryed this:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        try {
            new File("/storage/6391-A617/test").createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

, where 6391-A617 is my external SD Card (this time another one to test).
Result:

```
09-27 15:39:16.624 4965-4965/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder W/System.err: java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-27 15:39:16.633 4965-4965/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
09-27 15:39:16.633 4965-4965/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:226)
09-27 15:39:16.633 4965-4965/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:6588)
09-27 15:39:16.633 4965-4965/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6467)
09-27 15:39:16.633 4965-4965/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3738)
09-27 15:39:16.633 4965-4965/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3785)
09-27 15:39:16.633 4965-4965/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:157)
09-27 15:39:16.633 4965-4965/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
09-27 15:39:16.633 4965-4965/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-27 15:39:16.633 4965-4965/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
09-27 15:39:16.633 4965-4965/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
09-27 15:39:16.633 4965-4965/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-27 15:39:16.633 4965-4965/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
09-27 15:39:16.633 4965-4965/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
09-27 15:39:16.633 4965-4965/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-27 15:39:16.634 4965-4965/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
09-27 15:39:16.634 4965-4965/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
09-27 15:39:16.634 4965-4965/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:932)
09-27 15:39:16.634 4965-4965/me.bleuzen.android.screenrecorder W/System.err:    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Please post relevant code here directly. Include line 98 of  RecordingSession.java.

Comment: It's great you've added `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in your Manifest. Have you implemented Runtime Permission? In which OS version does the device is running?.

Comment: @SrikarReddy My test device: LG G4 (Android 6.0)
If I implemented Runtime Permission? Do you mean ask the user for permissions during app is running? If yes, I don't know how to implement this yet.

Comment: @Bleuzen please reread my previous comment.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm not sure what code is relevant for this problem and because of this app has little code, I decided to post the full code.

Comment: You haven't posted any code. You posted a link.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice ... to Dropbox, where you can download the code as zip archive.

Comment: It is better to copy and paste code here. Links can quickly become out of date. If that happens, then this question becomes less useful to any future visitors with a similar problem.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice But if I post the code here, it will make the desciption of this question much longer and you can't test it fast, because of the missing resources. It's better as zip: extract it, compile and test it yourself. I will keep future visitors in mind by creating a backup link. 3 links (commonsguy's example on github, 2 of me) should be enought for some years ;) And, by the way, you can take every code of a service, which wants to write to the external sd card. Anyway, let's continue finding a solution for this problem.

Comment: I can't post 2 links in my question. Backup link: http://www.mediafire.com/download/68vd8wewn3odo10/ASRsrc.zip
But how I said, you can also create your own code to test this.

Comment: When I say you should post code, I am referring to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This should be enough code to illustrate the issue you are asking about and no more. You can waste more time arguing or you can learn to follow instructions and get the help you want.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Question edited. I made a new example, independently to my other app, but this little example shows the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are running the app on Android 6.0, implementing Runtime permission is mandatory for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. This is the reason behind the crash.

Here are few links that get you started with implementing Runtime Permissions https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions
http://www.androidwarriors.com/2016/05/runtime-permissions-android-m-example.html

Comment: Because it is too long for a comment: http://pastebin.com/KZzUMM22
RecorderService.NOTIFY_ID in the code is just an int.

Comment: @Bleuzen If it's too long for a comment, you should edit your original question instead.

Comment: Take a look at my 2nd edit of this question. It also doesn't work in my MainActivity.